# Why doesn't the linker allow two variables in two different CPP files to have the same names unless they are static?

Tags: c++

A quick example to illustrate:

a.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

int do_foo_a();

#endif // A_H
```

b.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "a.h" 

int do_foo_b();

#endif // B_H
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"

int foo;

int do_foo_a()
{
    foo = 1;
    return foo;
}
```

b.cpp

```
#include "a.h"

int foo;

int do_foo_b()
{
    foo = 2;
    return foo;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "b.h"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << +do_foo_a() << std::endl;
    std::cout << +do_foo_b() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What does adding "static" before at least one of the two "int foo" do to the object files to prevent "multiple definitions of foo" and why is foo visible from other CPP files by default?

I was expecting the above code to work as-is, i.e. that the default behaviour is that cpp-file variables are isolated from eachother unless extern is used.

I'm looking for an answer that explains the "how" on the basis of what is contained in the object files - if possible illustrating with an example of disassembly.

Comment: *that the default behaviour is that cpp-file variables are isolated from eachother unless extern is used* That is not the default behavior.  The default is all variables are shared with all TU's at link time unless you specify they are local only to the single TU.

Comment: Thanks - yes, but why? extern is not difficult to use, and it feels safer to isolate everything by default.

Comment: @MisterMystère -- That is the way `static` works.  If you have a variable declared as `static` it is known only to that translation unit.  That `static int foo;` that is defined in A.cpp, knows nothing about the `static int foo;` defined in B.cpp.  They are two completely different variables, only known to that TU.

Comment: @MisterMystère because C did it first, because B did it first, because programs used to be small

Comment: There are two possibilities:  either a (global) variable in a source file (compilation units) is shared and accessed by multiple source files, or it is local to the particular source file.   There needs to be a way to make either choice in C++, since both have their uses.    Defaulting to sharing between compilation units (which requires the variable to be declared in all source files that use it, and defined in only one of them), and using `static` to specify local to a source file, is the method used in C++ - because C and precursor languages did it that way.

Comment: Thanks to all - special thanks to Peter for the nice summary. If anyone cares to explain the "how" part of the question, feel free to post an answer, but at least I know for the why.